# Disabling Nagle algorithm in Kestrel Web Server with ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-3.0

[ListenOptions.NoDelay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.listenoptions.nodelay?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is removed and not available in .NET Core 3.0 anymore. In the documentation for migrating to 3.0 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#transport-abstractions-moved-and-made-public) it says:

> NoDelay was moved from ListenOptions to the transport options.

But it doesn't show how this change shall be implemented.

How can I set the `NoDelay` option to false in .NET Core 3.0? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a package reference to

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv" Version="3.0.0" />
```

and invoke :

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder
            .UseLibuv(opts =>{
                opts.NoDelay = false;
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

See official docs on [Transport configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.0#transport-configuration)